# Weak Math Skillset: What is an 8-bit numerator and 8-bit denominator?

Tags: java, object, interface, binary, decimal

I'm embarrassed to say I wield weak math skills, and am a proud computer science major. I'm in a class, and it's overwhelming. This is a part of my homework assignment, however, I can't continue on it until I understand this section. Everyone in my class is struggling on writing a certain method to complete the assignment. I emailed my professor, asking for clarification on how the method should be written.

He said I am supposed to store an 8-bit numerator and an 8-bit denominator... however... I do **not** understand what a numerator and denominator is. Can someone please explain this to me?

This is part of the response I got from my professor:

> "[You're] supposed to encode the coefficients A, B, and C into the chromosome [*chromosome* is our interface, so *chromosome* **chrome** is our object].  A, B, and C are all numbers that can be fractional.  You must store an 8-bit numerator and an 8-bit denominator.  A, B, and C can also be positive or negative."

After we do this, we're supposed to map the `A, B, and C` into a binary string to create a new chromosome object.

How I am translating this: `A, B, and C` are going to be doubles (at least) holding a decimal value. But I can't implement this until I know what an 8-bit numerator and an 8-bit denominator is. Please help!

Thank you! <3 TG52

Comment: When dealing with fractions, the numerator is the top part of the fraction and the denominator is the bottom part.

Comment: Aaah okay!! So in java, is this 3.4 equivalent to 3/4? (3=numerator, 4=denominator). How would a variable hold that?

Comment: No!! 3/4 == 0.75. Remember some decimals cannot be expressed as fractions. You have to be careful of irrational numbers. 3.4 == 34/10. And this has **nothing** to do with Java. This is **pure** maths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is conjecture based on your post but what I believe your professor is asking for in this assignment is to represent the numerator and denominator of your fractions with 8-bit signed integers.

Using the `byte` data type will suffice in this case :

> byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.

So you could have a class called Fraction like:

```
class Fraction{
    private byte numerator;
    private byte denominator;

    public Fraction(byte numerator, byte denominator){
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }
}
```